# What will be the expected number of colliding balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are n balls $b_1...b_n$ and $n$ boxes. Each ball is placed in a box chosen independently and uniformly at random.We say that $(b_i,b_j)$ is a colliding pair if $i<j$ and $b_i$ and $b_j$ are placed in the same box.Find the expected number of colliding pair.

The p.d.f of choosing a box should be $\frac{1}{n}$, now if n balls need to be distributed into n box shouldn't we use $n+n-1\choose n $, and then find expected value. 
But the answer given is $\frac{n-1}{2}$, how should I do this?

Comment: Hint:  use indicator variables.  There are $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ pairs and each has probability $\frac 1n$ of being colliding.

Comment: @lulu But those events are not jointly independent (although pairwise I guess they are) - is there some magic rule or trick that makes that issue go away?

Comment: @TMM  Yes, there is.  [Linearity of Expectation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_Expectation_Function) holds regardless of dependence.